# How to show labels as a tooltip in a pie chart using d3js and reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I was trying to create a pie chart using d3js and so far have been able to display it on my webapp. However, only the values are shown on the slices of the pie chart, I would also like to add label to those slice so that the users know what each slice means with either a tooltip or just with an arrow pointing to each slice and depicting what each of them slices mean.

I send a object to the pie component from my app.js file where I get the data after calling an api. the object looks like this:

```
[{"emotion":"Positive","value":81},{"emotion":"Neutral","value":18},{"emotion":"Negative","value":0}]
```

So now only 81, 18 and 0 are showing on the slices in my pie chart. I want to show the emotions as labels for them too. How do I do that?

this is the pie component so far:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

const Pie = props => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const createPie = d3
    .pie()
    .value(d => d.value)
    .sort(null);
  const createArc = d3
    .arc()
    .innerRadius(props.innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(props.outerRadius);
  const colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  const format = d3.format(".2f");

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const data = createPie(props.data);
      const group = d3.select(ref.current);
      const groupWithData = group.selectAll("g.arc").data(data);

      groupWithData.exit().remove();

      const groupWithUpdate = groupWithData
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

      const path = groupWithUpdate
        .append("path")
        .merge(groupWithData.select("path.arc"));

      path
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("d", createArc)
        .attr("fill", (d, i) => colors(i));

      const text = groupWithUpdate
        .append("text")
        .merge(groupWithData.select("text"));

      text
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("transform", d => `translate(${createArc.centroid(d)})`)
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("font-size", 10)
        .text(d => format(d.value));
    },
    [props.data]
  );

  return (
    <svg width={props.width} height={props.height}>
      <g
        ref={ref}
        transform={`translate(${props.outerRadius} ${props.outerRadius})`}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default Pie;
```

this is how I send the data in app.js

```
 <Pie
          data={this.state.analysis.sentiments}
          width={200}
          height={200}
          innerRadius={0}
          outerRadius={100}
        />
```

this is just a demo codesandbox and the values are shown in the slices. But I also want the labels when you hover the slices
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3-pie-chart-djx8y